# Google protobuf and multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, protocol-buffers, google-ads-api

How do I use Google protocol buffers in a multiprocess script?

My use case is:

- pulling data from the new Google Ads API
- appending the objects with metadata
- modelling using the objects
- pushing the results to a database

**AdWords Campaign Wrapper Object**

I have an existing process for the old AdWords API, where I pull the data and store it in custom classes, e.g.

```
class Campaign(Represantable):
    def __init__(self, id, managed_customer_id, base_campaign_id, name, status, serving_status):
        self.id = id
        self.managed_customer_id = managed_customer_id
        self.base_campaign_id = base_campaign_id
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.serving_status = serving_status

    @classmethod
    def from_zeep(cls, campaign, managed_customer_id):
        return cls(
            campaign.id,
            managed_customer_id,
            campaign.baseCampaignId,
            campaign.name,
            campaign.status,
            campaign.servingStatus
        )
```

**Multiprocessing script**

If I want to pull campaigns from a dozen accounts, I can run the scripts that populate the `Campaign` objects in parallel using `pathos` (again code simplified for this example):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool

class WithParallelism(object):
    def __init__(self, parallelism_level):
        self.parallelism_level = parallelism_level

    def _parallel_apply(self, fn, collection, **kwargs):
        pool = ProcessPool(
            nodes=self.parallelism_level
        )
        
        # this is to prevent Python from printing large traces when user interrupts execution (e.g. Ctrl+C)
        def keyboard_interrupt_wrapper_fn(*args_wrapped):
            try:
                return fn(*args_wrapped, **kwargs)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass
            except Exception as err:
                return err

        errors = pool.map(keyboard_interrupt_wrapper_fn, collection)

        return error
```

**Google Ads Campaign Wrapper Object**

With the **new** API, I planned to store the protobuf object within my class, and use pointers to access the objects attributes.  My class is a lot more complex than the example, using descriptors and subclass init for the attributes, but for simplicity it's effectively something like this:

```
class Campaign(Proto):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if "proto" in kwargs:
            self._proto = kwargs['proto']
        if "parent" in kwargs:
            self._parent = kwargs['parent']
        self._init_metadata(**kwargs)


    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._proto.id.value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._proto.name.value

   ...
```

This has the added advantage of being able to traverse the `parent` Google Ads object, to extract data from that `protobuf` object.

However, when I run my script of to populate these new objects in parallel, I get a `pickle` error.  I understand that `multiprocess` uses `pickle` to serialize the objects, and one of the key advantages of `protobuf` objects is that they can be easily serialized.

How should I go about pulling the new Google Ads data in parallel:

- Should I be serializing and deserializing the data in the `Campaign` object using `SerializeToString`
- Should I just be extracting and storing the scalar data (`id`, `name`)  like how I did with AdWords
- Is there an entirely different approach?